# i would like to random number but no repetition im coding above is it correct?

Tags: java, numbers, generate

What I am trying to do is generate random number but no repetition i'm coding above is it correct?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayLast = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int arrayitems : getArray(10, 100)) {
        arrayLast.add(arrayitems);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getArray(int arraysize, int range){
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arraybase = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++) {
        arraybase.add(new Integer(i));
    }

    int k =0;       
    for (int j = 0; j < arraysize; j++) {
        if(range>arraysize) {
            int sayi = rnd.nextInt(range-arraysize);
            array.add(arraybase.get(sayi));
            arraybase.remove(sayi);
        }
        else {  
            int sayi = rnd.nextInt(arraysize-k);
            array.add(arraybase.get(sayi));
            arraybase.remove(sayi);
            k++;
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(array);         
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Stream API in Java 8+, you can generate `n` distinct integers with a range from `origin` (inclusive) to `bound` (exclusive) by using this method:

```java
public static List<Integer> randomInts(int n, int origin, int bound) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(origin, bound)
            .distinct()
            .limit(n)
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
}
```

Example:

```java
// generate 15 distinct random numbers greater than or equal to 10 and less than 90
List<Integer> randoms = randomInts(15, 10, 90);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is unnecessarily complex. A simpler way is as follows:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        final int SIZE = 10;
        final int RANGE = 100;
        Random random = new Random();
        while (set.size() != SIZE) {
            set.add(random.nextInt(RANGE));
        }
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
[83, 67, 86, 39, 56, 26, 92, 60, 13, 94]
```

Note that a `Set` keep only unique values. So, any duplicate random number added to it will be automatically discarded.

---

**Alternatively,**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 10;
        final int RANGE = 100;
        Random random = new Random();
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(RANGE)).distinct().limit(SIZE).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
[54, 62, 14, 5, 30, 76, 7, 9, 63, 61]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing it this way. If the size and range are significantly different then using `sets` or `streams` with `distinct` is fine.  But if the size and range are close those methods can take a relatively long time to complete.

The downside to this algorithm is that it initializes an internal array first.  I find this is insignificant in most cases and the increase in speed for large values of both size and range is very significant.

It works as follows:

- assume an array of ints from `0` to `N`.
- generate a random int `k` between `0` and `N`
- assign that value to the return array.
- replace the k'th value with the Nth value
- then decrease `N` by `1`
- and repeat until `N == 0`

Since `k` has been effectively removed from the list of available values and replaced with the unassigned `Nth` value, that value will never be selected again.

```
     public static   int [] getRandom(int size, int range) {
         Random r = new Random();
         int[] ret = new int[size];
         // initialize number pool
         int[] nums = IntStream.range(0,range).toArray();

         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int k = r.nextInt(range);
            ret[i] = nums[k];
            range--;
            nums[k] = nums[range];
         }
         return ret;
       }
```

To test this, I recommend the following. The set is filled just to show there are no duplicates. Ironically, filling the set to prove a point takes more time than the actual generation of values.

```
        int[] v = getRandom(10_000_000, 10_000_000);
        System.out.println("Done! Filling set");
        Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(v)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
        System.out.printf("%,d%n",set.size());
        System.out.printf("%,d%n",v.length);
```

Prints

```
Done! Filling set.
10,000,000
10,000,000
```